# How can I make an HTML page accessible with buttons for my worker threads?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, worker

Right now I have some code I wrote in puppeteer and I'm using express too. It accesses various chrome profiles and then it does some actions. To start these worker threads I run index.js then go into my browser and type in http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chrome?profile=(profilename) which starts a worker thread on that specific chrome profile. I have to do this for each chrome profile that I have.

Now I would like to be able to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in my browser and then be able to see my profile names with buttons next to them which will open and close the worker thread when clicked. How can I do this? I've tried many things and I think it would be a waste of them posting them here because I couldn't get anything to work.

index.js

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);

let portCounter = 9444;

app.get("/api/chrome", (request, response) => {
  const profile = request.query.profile;

  worker(profile, {
    
    remoteDebuggingPort: portCounter++,
  });

  return response.status(200).send("Booting the browser");
});

function worker(profile, data = {}) {
  const startWorker = () => {
    const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", {
      workerData: {
        ...data,
        profile: profile,
      },
    });

    worker.profile = profile;

    worker.on("message", (message) => {
      console.log(`Message back from worker: ${message}`);
    });

    worker.on("error", (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
      console.log(`Worker exited - ${code} ++ ${worker.profile}`);
      
      startWorker();
    });

    return worker;
  };

  return startWorker();
}

http.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("HTTP server started on 127.0.0.1:8000");
});
```

worker.js

```
let { workerData, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true,
    args: [
      `--remote-debugging-port=${workerData.remoteDebuggingPort}`,
      "--user-data-dir=D:/chrome-profiles/" + workerData.profile,
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-default-browser-check",
      `--window-size=1920,1080`,
    ],
    defaultViewport: null,
    timeout: 60000, 
    slowMo: 50, 
  });

  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));

  const pages = await browser.pages();
  const page = pages[0];

  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");
```

Either I couldn't open those existing chrome profiles or my worker.js file would not run after the browser opened. I've been able to loop and get all of my chrome profiles to display but when I launched a profile it would just sit there and not do any actions inside of the worker.js.